# Shopify page template product loop

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

Just wondering why this is not populating products in the Shopify page template but it's working normally in the article template:

```
{%- assign firstsecthandle = page.metafields.first-sect.rev-handle -%}
{% for product in collections[ firstsecthandle ].products  %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

As a result of this, I get the list of collections instead of products on page template but on the article template I get products.

On the page template it works only if I put the exact URL handle of collection:

But I need collection-handle to be dynamically declared not to have static value.

A variant which is working with a static 'collection-handle':

```html
{% for product in collections.collection-handle.products %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: "As a result of this, I get the list of collections instead of products on page template but on the article template I get products." - this doesn't make any sense. You can't get a list of collection using that code. You definitely have other code in place that does that

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me also, and I was looking to find an issue, but can't see the reason.

Comment: Add please what's in your `for` loop and the output you're getting.